# How to change the background color of negative value in a cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a table with some numbers in it at different cells.
I want to check if any of the cell has a `value < 0`, it may change its row's background color to red!
I want function to be called on a button click, and it may check entire document's tables.
This is what I am using:

```
function checkNegative(){
    function(e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);
        var checkNeg = function(c) {
            for(var i=0,$ci; i<c.length; i++) {
                $ci = $(c[i]);
                if(parseInt($ci.text()) < 0) $ci.css("color", "red");
                else $ci.css("color", "black");
            }
        };
        checkNeg($target.parents("table").find("[td]"));
    }
}
```

I found this over Internet, but not working for my case!
Please help!
My Table looks like this:

```
<table border="1" bordercolor="#bababb">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>NUMBER1</th>
            <th>NUMBER2</th>
            <th>NUMBER3</th>
            <th>NUMBER4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1202</td>
        <td>2587</td>
        <td>-2541</td>
        <td>3652</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1202</td>
        <td>2587</td>
        <td>2541</td>
        <td>-3652</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1202</td>
        <td>-2587</td>
        <td>2541</td>
        <td>3652</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-1202</td>
        <td>2587</td>
        <td>2541</td>
        <td>3652</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-1202</td>
        <td>2587</td>
        <td>-2541</td>
        <td>3652</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1202</td>
        <td>-2587</td>
        <td>-2541</td>
        <td>3652</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi MHS, I feel you are little ambiguous in asking the question. You question title speaks something and the description speaks something else. Can you please be specific about your problem because in title you mention javascript and red background-color for cells with negative value while the description says something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I've a solution for the problem. I assume a table with 6 rows and 4 columns with positive and negative values.

I also have a javascript method which does the colouring of the background depending on positive or negative values. Please find the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/GSWBW/1/)

The script is:

```
var formatBackground=function(){
    var table, tbody, rowCount, cellCount, value;
    table=document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
    if(table.childNodes[1]) tbody=table.childNodes[1];
    if(tbody) rowCount=tbody.childNodes.length;

    for(i=0;i<rowCount;i++){
        cellCount=tbody.childNodes[i].childNodes.length;

        for(j=1;j<cellCount;j++){
            value=tbody.childNodes[i].childNodes[j].outerText;
            if(parseInt(value)<0) tbody.childNodes[i].childNodes[j].setAttribute('style','background-color: #f00');
            j+=1;
        }
        i+=1;
    }
};
```

Comment: Rupam Datta: My table structures are like this:
<table><thead><th>HEADING</th></thead><tbody><tr><td>BLA BLA</td></tr></tbody></table>
please help!!!

Comment: Rupam Datta: Please Check the Updated Question.

Comment: Hey MHS, I've updated the fiddle according to your html structure. please find the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/GSWBW/3/

Answer (score 2):

```
<table id="your_table_id">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>-3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>-2</th>
        <th>-1</th>
        <th>0</th>
        <th>5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>+5</td>
        <td>-3</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>-2.3</td>
    </tr>
</table>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#your_table_id td").each(function(){
            var txt = $(this).text();
            if( !isNaN(txt) && parseInt(txt) < 0 )
                $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'red');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please tell me how can I call it on button click? and I want my whole document to be checked not just a single table! Please help!!! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Change `$("#your_table_id td")` to `$("table td")` is OK.

Answer (score 1):

So, with minimal changes to your code to make it work:

```
var checkNeg = function(c) {
    for(var i=0,$ci; i<c.length; i++) {
        $ci = $(c[i]);
        console.log(i, parseInt($ci.text()));
        if(parseInt($ci.text()) < 0) $ci.css("color", "red");
        else $ci.css("color", "black");
    }
};

$('table *').click(function(e) {
    checkNeg($(e).closest("table").find("td"));
});
```

The syntax error was due to the anonymous function (`function(e) { ... }`) wrapping things without being utilised in any way (i.e. neither invoked nor stored in a variable).

The `"[td]"` selector I talked about in the comments would have selected all nodes that have the *attribute* named `td`, for example `<div td="foo">`; not the `td` elements. To do that, you need `"td"` selector.

And to actually respond to clicks in the table, you need to have a click handler.

The inner code itself I did not touch; Allen Chak's answer shows you a nicer way to do the same thing, but either should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change the jQuery selector from '#your_table_id td' to 'table td', and call the function in a clickhandler, something like this:

```
var checkNegative = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('table td').each(function() {
        //Allen Chak's code here
    });
}

$('#mybutton').click(checkNegative);
```

And I don't mean to be rude, but if you can not figure this kind of changes out yourself, I advise you to do yourself a favour, and make a bit more study of javascript and jQuery. You can just implement this and be happy it works, but you'll be far better off actually understanding what you code ;)